# convert array of bitmaps to array of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have an array of Bitmaps that I'm trying to convert into an array of bytes where each index of the byte array represents a Bitmap. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do this. If anyone has a suggestion, let me know. Thanks!

```
private void ConvertBitmapToBytes(Bitmap[] BitmapArray)
{
    byte[][] BitmapBytes = new byte[BitmapArray.Length][];
    ImageConverter convert = new ImageConverter();
    for (int i = 0; i < BitmapArray.Length; i++)
    {
        BitmapBytes[i] = new byte[BitmapArray.Length];
        BitmapBytes[i][i] = convert.ConvertTo(BitmapArray[i], typeof(byte[]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap image){
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        return imageBytes;
    }
}
```

And then, your code will become this:

```
private void ConvertBitmapToBytes(Bitmap[] BitmapArray)
{
    byte[][] BitmapBytes = new byte[BitmapArray.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < BitmapArray.Length; i++)
    {
        BitmapBytes[i] = ImageToByte(BitmapArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!